# How to get dynamically added UI element from C#

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a problem with getting to properties of dynamically added field.

If I do something like that

```
<Rectangle Name="field_0_0" Width="10" Height="10" />
```

then in C# code I can get to this by

```
field_0_0.Width = 20;
```

But in my app I've done something like this

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        String fieldName = "field_" + i + "_" + j;
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
        rec.Name = fieldName;
        Container.Children.Add(rec);
    }
 }
```

Now the problem is that I don't know how to call these fields in my code when I have them on screen? For example I want to change fill color of `field_1_1`

How can I get this rectangle from name ?

Comment: why can't you enumerate `Container.Children` and look for your rectangle?

Comment: cause If I'll have 100000 rectangles looping every time to find one will waste a lot of time

Comment: CPU time? The FindName method probably does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) method.

```
object findRect = Container.FindName("field_1_1");
if (findRect is Rectangle)
{        
    Rectangle rect = findRect as Rectangle;
    //change rect properties
}
```